# Can you please give me a link or a guide on how to add custom API, controllers, models, and migrations to the simple Laravel package I created?

Tags: laravel

Can you please give me a link or a guide on how to add custom API, controllers, models, and migrations to the simple Laravel package I created?

Laravel package development.

**Here is the composer.json of the package.**

````
    "name": "test/greetr",
    "description": "Greetr - A simple Laravel package.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Test Package",
            "email": "test_package@test.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Test\\Greetr\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}```


**Here is the class.**

```<?php

namespace Ac3\Greetr;

class Greetr
{
    public function greet(String $sName)
    {
        return 'Hi ' . $sName . '! How are you doing today?';
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use Service Provider to load your routes, views, and database migrations. Then you can use it in your composer.json file.

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "YourServiceProvider"
        ]
    }
}
```

For more details refer to [Laravel Package Development](https://laravelpackage.com/). It provides a complete guide to developing a Laravel package from scratch to end.